# Java tcp client on localhost connecting to android server on emulator

Tags: android, sockets, emulation

I developed an Android server and tried to test it using the emulator:

Here's the Android server code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static String TAG = "ServerSocketTest";
private ServerSocket server;

Runnable conn = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(53000);

            while (true) {
                Log.d(TAG, "server waiting for connection");
                Socket socket = server.accept();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                String str = in.readLine();

                Log.i("received response from server", str);

                in.close();
                socket.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {             
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new Thread(conn).start();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {      
    super.onPause();
    if (server != null) {
        try {
            server.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}   

 }
```

Now the problem is how can I get my TCP client to connect to this server on emulator?

I have this line in the client. This client is Java running on desktop:

```
clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 53000);
```

but i get IOException...
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by [using redirection in Android console](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking).